# ¿Cómo puedo consultar todos los datos de varias tablas de un solo registro en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta en postgresql.
Tengo 6 tablas las cuales se relacionan entre sí, está primeramente la tabla madre (por así decirlo) que es la tabla "innovadores", cuya clave primaria PK es "id_innovador", las demás tablas poseen una clave foránea FK que hace relación con la clave primaria de la tabla madre antes mencionada.

Lo que deseo hacer es consultar todos los datos de todas las tablas relacionadas, hasta ahí todo bien porque me arroja todos los datos por medio de INNER JOIN.
Sin embargo, me trae todos los registros, y yo solamente quiero consultar todos los datos pero de un solo registro; intenté usando un WHERE denotando que debe ser cuando el "id_innovador" sea el que deseo obtener, pero me dice que el código es ambiguo.

Aquí les dejo el comando que estaba intentando colocar.

```
SELECT *
    FROM innovadores
    INNER JOIN datos_residencia ON datos_residencia.id_innovador = innovadores.id_innovador 
    INNER JOIN tipo_innovador ON tipo_innovador.id_innovador = innovadores.id_innovador 
    INNER JOIN datos_profesion ON datos_profesion.id_innovador = innovadores.id_innovador
    INNER JOIN datos_curso ON datos_curso.id_innovador = innovadores.id_innovador
    INNER JOIN datos_laboral ON datos_laboral.id_innovador = innovadores.id_innovador WHERE id_innovador = ?
```

Comment: Creo que cuando te refieres a un registro quieres decir un campo de una tabla concreta. en vez de todos los campos con el asterisco.
para eso tienes que ponerlo delante del nombre de la tabla tal que así

`SELECT datos_residencia.id_innovador FROM innovadores ......`

Bienvenido a stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

En el `WHERE` te dice que el `id_innovador` es ambiguo porque ese campo existe en mas de una tabla,**debes de indicarle de que tabla es el campo**, por ejemplo `innovadores.id_innovador`.

Comment: LIsto, justamente eso era, ya me funciona la consulta. ¡Muchas gracias!